# Add Analytical badge to Area 51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, badge-request, analytical-badge

There is an Analytical badge for "Visited every section of the FAQ" on every normal Stack Exchange but there is no such badge on Area 51. Badges are for encouraging and rewarding wanted behavior and if it's relevant to have people read the FAQ on any other site it's as relevant on Area 51. Also, encouraging people to read the FAQ on Area 51 makes sense because Area 51 works very differently than other Stack Exchange sites. Therefore, I'd suggest to add an Analytical badge to Area 51.

Someone might say "Wait! The [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) does not have linked sections, so we can't track peoples' progress in reading it." My answer: What's stopping you from creating linked sections in the Area 51 FAQ? Linked section would make an improvement in any case.

I notice that there already is a badge with a similar name on Area 51, [the Analyst bade](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/94/analyst). I do not think that this is an issue though. [Badges are supposed to be a little mysterious.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/a-bevy-of-new-badges/)

Comment: How many people who earn the "analytical" badge actually read the FAQ?  It's one of the easiest badges to game, if not *the* easiest.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I thought you could only get the analytical badge by clicking on every section in under 5 seconds.  Always worked for me.  :-)

Comment: @KevinVermeer By your argument, if it shouldn't be added to Area 51, then it should be removed from other sites.

Comment: @N.N. - Correct.  As Lars noted, the standard way to get the badge is to just click through the sections.  It's a useless badge.  I don't think it does any harm, but I don't think that adding the badge to A51 will do any good, either.

Comment: @KevinVermeer It will do good in *encouraging* people to read the FAQ, it's especially useful for Area 51 since its FAQ is very different from the other sites' FAQs. Also it will do good in the adding to the consistency to the badge system.